# ISR cannot change extern struct field in C embedded

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, hal

I've got a problem with STM32F091RCT on Nucleo, which I use for controlling the stepper motor driver DRV8825.

The main goal of the code section below is to stop the stepper motor when it rotates too much, using interrupt from Hall switch and a magnet. I'm also using HAL libraries for STM32 and of course C language.

I've got these files:

motor.h:

```
typedef struct{
   volatile uint8_t STOP_FLAG
} Motor;
```

motor.c:

```
#include "motor.h"

void ClearStopFlag(Motor *motor)
{
  motor->STOP_FLAG = 0;
}

void SetStopFlag(Motor *motor)
{
  motor->STOP_FLAG = 1;
}

uint8_t GetStopFlag(Motor *motor)
{
  return motor->STOP_FLAG;
}

void Init(Motor *motor)
{
  ClearStopFlag(motor); 
}

void Rotate(Motor *motor)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)      // every iteration is a motor step
  {
    if(GetStopFlag(motor)) break;
    // irrelevant code switching the output used for driver step input ----
  }
}

void Disable(Motor *motor)
{
  // Code that sets the GPIO pin responsible for ENABLE pin in the driver ----
}
```

hall.c:

```
#include "motor.h"
#include "exec.h"

extern Motor m;

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  SetStopFlag(&m);
}
```

exec.c:

```
#include "hall.h"
#include "motor.h"

Motor m;

void SomeFunction(void)
{
  Init(&m);
  Rotate(&m); // here GPIO ISR in hall.c doesn't set the STOP_FLAG while Rotate() is executing
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "exec.h"
int main(void)
{
  SomeFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

First of all, the original code is much more complex, I have not included here some headers which are used for function prototypes, other Motor struct fields, other functions etc. I don't have access to the code right now it is also much more cleaner that way.

I've tested it a lot and the problem is that the GPIO interrupt callback function cannot change the STOP_FLAG variable. This is how it behaves:

- the interrupt works well - when i try to turn on the diode in interrupt section - it turns on; when i try to **disable the driver using Disable() function from motor.c it works and sets the proper GPIO port**
- when i try to set the STOP_FLAG in ISR whitout a function, that is using `m->STOP_FLAG = 1;` it doesn't work
- when i call the SetStopFlag() function from exec.c (eg. in SomeFunction() before the Rotate() line) it works properly

Does somebody know why hall.c has a problem accessing the struct field?

Comment: `if(GetStopFlag) break;` -> `if(GetStopFlag(motor)) break;`

Comment: i'm sorry, my bad -  i've missed it here because I've wrote it right now and didn't copy it from a source code, but it's a typo and doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You are passing your `motor` around in some very sporadic way. Sometimes as global, sometimes as parameter. Sometimes receiving it as parameter, but then for some reason use the global. Clean this mess up first. And yeah, I believe the `m` itself should be `volatile`.

Comment: The reason i'm using a global Motor variable is because the exec.c file is dedicated to work with two motors. It controls the commands received from UART and execute them by calling proper motor functions. The motor.c file is a general stepper motor code operating on Motor object - it rotates it, enables it etc., and the exec.c file is managing two motors, so all of the exec.c functions have access to the global Motor objects. (and the hall sensor ISR have access to the motor object as well)
I've made a struct field `volatile` in a struct declaration, isn't it enough?

Comment: IMO your code is a complete mess calles a spaghetti code. If the minimal looks like this I can imagine what is in the actual one. Probalby many things change this variable (and another probably as well) simultaneously and I do no see any mechanisms used in the multi thread programs, I think that this the main reason of the @strange values@ in it.

Comment: Does the code behave differently if you disable compiler optimizations?  Use the debugger.  Step through the disassembly.  Does the ISR use the correct address for motor?  Does the Rotate function really reread the stop flag every loop iteration?

Comment: Don't qualify struct members. Qualify the struct itself. And yes this is spaghetti code.

Comment: I'm not an advanced programmer so could somebody tell me why is it a spaghetti code?
I've got module which provides interface for motor driver.
I've got module which operates on motors the way i want it to be in my particular application, using the driver interface.
I've got module which controlls the special case of stopping the motor, accesing its field using setter.
I don't get why it seems to be unreadable or error vulnerable.
Actually, hall ISR is the only thing that changes this variable, and I don't think I need to manage threads because this is a simple application.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem is somewhere else.

**It is not reproducible with the code you have provided.**

I have created a minimal CubeMX project for a Discovery board with two LEDs (`LD3` on `PB7` and `LD4` on `PB6`) and a pushbutton (`B1` on `PA0`), then added your code.

`motor.c`: changed the loop to an endless one, since I don't trust myself to be able to push the button in a few microseconds, and measure the difference

```
void Rotate(Motor *motor)
{
  while(1)      // every iteration is a motor step
  {
    if(GetStopFlag(motor))
        break;
    // irrelevant code switching the output used for driver step input ----
  }
}
```

`main.c`: Added initialization and feedback.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_hal.h"

void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) {
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(B1_Pin);
}

void EXTILine0_Config(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure = { 0 };
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = B1_Pin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
}

int main(void) {
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  EXTILine0_Config();
  SomeFunction();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  while(1)
      ;
}
```

The rest is identical.

Compiled it with this compiler:
`arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major) 7.2.1 20170904 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 255204]` and these options: `-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O3 -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -Wall -Wextra  -g3 -std=gnu11`

and it works as expected. Pressing the button triggers the EXTI interrupt, flag in the struct is set, loop stops, and LD4 lights up.